# Missing a driver for a SMB-accessed Brother printer

Tags: drivers, samba, printer, proprietary-drivers, brother

I use Lubuntu 17.10. I'm not quite sure which spooling mechanism my own system uses (I think it's CUPS). Now, I want to connect to a printer attached to another machine on a LAN; it's a Windows machine which exposes the printer via SMB. I do "see" the printer, so when using the LXDE printing utility to add a printer I get to the stage where I need to select a driver.

And this is where my problem is: The printer is a Brother HL-L2300D. I see a driver for other Brother models, but not this one. After looking online, I found [this page](http://support.brother.com/g/b/downloadlist.aspx?c=us&lang=en&prod=hll2300d_us_eu_as&os=128), which offers me several installation packages. I'm not sure which to try, both because I'm not sure about the spooling mechanism (I mean, I think I have CUPS, but is that actually used for SMB printers?), and because when I try the "install tool" it suggests it intends to install i386 packages and I'm worried about incompatibilities.

So - am I barking up the wrong tree and need to get this working some other way? Or do I actually need one of those packages? In the latter case, some directions on what exactly to install would be appreciated.

Comment: On [OpenPrinting](http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Brother/Brother-HL-L2300D), there's a report that the proprietary drivers work well on amd64.